# 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error.

What could be causing this?

Here the .htaccess:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you need any more information please let me know, I will add it to the question.

Comment: What happens when you comment lines out?  For example, if you `#` comment out the first two lines (php_flag, php_value), does it work properly?

Comment: Not sure, but I think `RewriteRule` shouldn't be separated from its `RewriteCond`. Remove the empty line.

Comment: @cale_b It does work. Thank you. If you would be so kind and add the answer what the reason is, I will accept your answer.

Comment: BTW. It was working fine before like this, until some update on the hosting package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines may be causing the problem:

```
php_flag display_errors on  
php_value error_reporting 9999
```

If a server runs PHP in "CGI mode", these commands will cause a 500 internal server error.

I would recommend commenting them out as follows, or removing them completely:

```
# php_flag display_errors on  
# php_value error_reporting 9999
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the mod_rewrite module by running the following command.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Also make sure that in your conf file (httpd.conf for earlier apache versions, apache2.conf for apache 2.*), in the directive Directory, you set **AllowOverride None** to **Allow Override All**.